# Getting jmeter error: java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution

Tags: jmeter-4.0

I am a beginner to jmeter. I am trying to perform a simple load test using jmeter 4.0. I created a HTTP sampler and added a view results tree listener.
[HTTP Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipzf6.png)

But getting the below error under Response data in results tree.

> "java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not
>   receive a response from an authoritative server   at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:697)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:455)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"

All requests are getting failed. There is no problem in internet connectivity. Please resolve my issue.

Comment: Can you provide protocol before server name as "https" let me know its resolved or not

Comment: I have checked that too. Still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced same issue. Found solution using below steps:

1.
Protocol:http/https
server name/IP:google.com
port & path:blank(as no params)

2. add proxy details if required